# Save Offline SQLite Database in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I try to create and save the offline SQLite database for send job profile.But the the database is not created.
Please tell me how to create sqlite database and represent that in the file explorer.

Fragment.java

```
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.app.Service;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.graphics.Typeface;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.location.LocationListener;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.IBinder;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.sunmobileappnow.mobileappnow.*;

    public class FragmentSendJob extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
    // this Fragment will be called from MainActivity

    private Button submit,cancel;
       private EditText ename,mobno,picktime,unit,street,suburb,destination,fare,city;
    private Spinner state,group;
    private ViewGroup vgroup ;
       private String sename,smobno,spicktime,sunit,sstreet,ssuburb,sstate, ssendjob,scity,sdestination,sfare,sgroup,login_token;
       private static FragmentDialog dialog;
    private  SendJobDataBase db; 
    static final int DIALOG_ID = 0;
    private Typeface ftype;
    private SharedPreferences pref1;
    String latitude,longitude;
    public FragmentSendJob(){}

    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
          {
           View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sendjob_fragment, container, false);
           pref1=this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("LocDetails", getActivity().MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
           latitude = pref1.getString("latitude","latitude"); 
           longitude = pref1.getString("longitude","longitude"); 

           ename = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ename);
           mobno  = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mobno);
           picktime  = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.picktime);
           unit  = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.unit);
           street  = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.street);
           suburb  = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.suburb);
           destination  = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.destination);
           state = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.state);
           fare=(EditText)  rootView.findViewById(R.id.fare);
           group = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.group);
           city  = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.city);
           vgroup = (ViewGroup) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rel); 
           submit = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.submit);
           submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

         public void onClick(View v) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub


         new SendJob().execute();
                   Intent intent =new Intent(getActivity(),GetCurrentLocation.class);
                   startActivity(intent); 

                   System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+latitude+"***********");
                   System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>"+longitude+"***********");


         }

         });

           cancel = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
           cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for (int i = 0, count = vgroup.getChildCount(); i < count; ++i) {
       View view = vgroup.getChildAt(i);
       if (view instanceof EditText) {
           ((EditText)view).setText("");
       }
    }

    }   
    });

           String[] mystate= new String[]{"Select state","New South Wales","Victoria","Queensland","Northern Territory","Western Australia","South Australia"}; 
           ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), R.layout.listrow, mystate);

    state.setAdapter(adapter);  

    state.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int pos, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    scity =  state.getSelectedItem().toString();

      String s1=arg0.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
    if(s1.equals("New South Wales"))
    city.setText("Sydney");
    else if(s1.equals("Victoria"))
    city.setText("Melbourne");
        else if(s1.equals("Queensland"))
    city.setText("Brisbane");
    else if(s1.equals("Northern Territory"))
    city.setText("Darwin");
    else if(s1.equals("Western Australia"))
    city.setText("Perth");
    else if(s1.equals("South Australia"))
    city.setText("Adelaide");

                                }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    });


    String[] mygroups= new String[]{"Select Groups","My Group","My Secondary group","Everyone"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapters = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(),
    R.layout.listrow, mygroups);
    group.setAdapter(adapters);

    group.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
    int pos, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ssendjob = group.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
    //gender.setText(setgender);
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    });
       return rootView;
          }




          private class SendJob extends AsyncTask<String, String, String[]> {
    ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

       @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(final String... params) 
    {
    ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
    && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
    && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) 
    {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try 
    {
    JSONObject job= new JSONObject();
    sename = ename.getText().toString();
    smobno = mobno.getText().toString();
    spicktime = picktime.getText().toString();
    sunit = unit.getText().toString();
    sstreet = street.getText().toString();
    ssuburb = suburb.getText().toString();
    sstate = state.getSelectedItem().toString();
    scity = city.getText().toString();
    sdestination = destination.getText().toString();
    sgroup = group.getSelectedItem().toString();
    sfare = fare.getText().toString();


    sename.replace("" ,"%20");
    smobno.replace("" ,"%20");
    spicktime.replace("" ,"%20");
    sunit.replace("" ,"%20");
    sstreet.replace("" ,"%20");
    sstate.replace("" ,"%20"); 
    ssuburb.replace("" ,"%20");
    scity.replace("" ,"%20");
    sdestination.replace("" ,"%20");
    sgroup.replace("" ,"%20");
    sfare.replace("" ,"%20");



        job.put("name",sename);
    job.put("mobile_no",smobno);
    job.put("pickup_time",spicktime);
    job.put("unit_no",sunit);
    job.put("street_name",sstreet);
    job.put("state",sstate);
    job.put("suburb",ssuburb);
    job.put("city",scity);
    job.put("destination",sdestination);
    job.put("group",sgroup);
    job.put("fare",sfare);
    job.put("latitude",latitude);
    job.put("longitude",longitude);

    job.put("status_key","2");
    job.put("method","send_job");
        job.put("login_token",login_token);

       StringEntity se = new StringEntity(job.toString());
       HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://suntechwebsolutions.com/clients/mobileapp_now/webservice.php");
       httppost.setEntity(se);
               HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
               String data = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

    Log.i("response", data);
    System.out.println("response "+data);
               String call;
       call = data;


       System.out.println(" print me.............."+call);


      System.out.println(sename+".....please print my name......."+login_token);
         System.out.println(smobno+"......please print my name......."+smobno);
          System.out.println(sstate +"......please print my name......."+sstate);
          System.out.println(sstreet+"........please print my name......."+street);
       System.out.println(login_token+".....please print my name......."+login_token);
          System.out.println(ssuburb+"......please print my name......."+suburb);
          System.out.println(sgroup +"......please print my name......."+group);
          System.out.println(sdestination+"........please print my name......."+destination);
          System.out.println(scity+"......please print my name......."+city);
          System.out.println(sfare +"......please print my name......."+fare);
          System.out.println(spicktime+"........please print my name......."+spicktime);    


    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(data);
    Log.d("response", jo.toString(4));
    JSONArray jArray = jo.getJSONArray("driver_details");  
    Log.d("Array", jArray.toString(4));


    for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
    {
    try {
       JSONObject jsob = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

               sename= jsob.getString("sename");
               smobno = jsob.getString("mobile_no");
               spicktime = jsob.getString("pickup_time");
           sstreet = jsob.getString("street_name");
           ssuburb = jsob.getString("Suburb");
           sstate = jsob.getString("State");
           sgroup = jsob.getString("group");
           sdestination = jsob.getString("destination");
           scity = jsob.getString("city");
           sfare = jsob.getString("fare");
               login_token=jsob.getString("login_token");

               db = new SendJobDataBase(getApplicationContext());   
    db.insert(sename,smobno, spicktime, sunit, sstreet,sstate, ssuburb,scity, sdestination, sgroup, sfare); 


       Object pref = getSharedPreferences("Driver");
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit= ((SharedPreferences) pref).edit();

    edit.putString("sename", sename);
    edit.putString("smobno", smobno);
    edit.putString("spicktime",  spicktime);
    edit.putString("sunit", sunit);
    edit.putString("sstreet", sstreet);
                                   edit.putString("sstate", sstate);
    edit.putString("ssuburb", ssuburb);
    edit.putString("scity", scity);
    edit.putString("sdestination", sdestination);
    edit.putString("sgroup", sgroup);
    edit.putString("sfare", sfare);
    edit.putString("latitude",latitude);
    edit.putString("longitude",longitude);

    edit.putString("status_key","2");
    edit.putString("method","send_job");
    edit.putString("login_token",login_token);

        edit.commit();  



    } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
       } 

    /*System.out.println("response "+data);
               String call;
       call = data;*/



    if(jo.getString("err-code").equals("0"))
    {
    final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    alert.setTitle("Alert!!!");
    alert.setMessage(jo.getString("message"));
    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
    int whichButton) 
    {
    pDialog.dismiss();


                             dialog.dismiss();


                                            }

    });
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    alert.show();
    }
    });
    }
    else
    {
    final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    alert.setTitle("Alert !");
    alert.setMessage(jo.getString("message"));
    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
    int whichButton) {
    dialog.dismiss();


    }
    });
    }
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
    {
    public void run() 
    {
    pDialog.dismiss();
                                               //alert.show();
    }
    });
    }

    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    return params;
    }
    private Object getSharedPreferences(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
    }
    private Context getApplicationContext() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) 
    {

    super.onPostExecute(result);
    }   
          }



    public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    }



SendJobDatabase.java

    package com.sunmobile.navigationdrawer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SendJobDataBase 
{
   private static final  String DATABASE_NAME = "myjob.db";
   private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
   static final String TABLE_NAME = "jobsend";
   private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
   private static Context context;
   static SQLiteDatabase db;
   private final ArrayList<member> user = new ArrayList<member>();

   OpenHelper helper;
   private SQLiteStatement insertStmt;
   private static final String INSERT = "insert into " + TABLE_NAME + " (sename,smobno,spicktime,sunit,sstreet,ssuburb,sstate,scity,sdestination,sfare,sgroup) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
protected static final String enternpw = null;
   public SendJobDataBase(Context context) {
   SendJobDataBase.context = context;
   OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(SendJobDataBase.context);
   SendJobDataBase.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
   this.insertStmt = SendJobDataBase.db.compileStatement(INSERT);
   }
   public long insert(String sename,String smobno,String spicktime,String sunit,String sstreet,String ssuburb,String sstate,String scity,String sdestination,String sfare,String sgroup) {
   this.insertStmt.bindString(1, sename);
   this.insertStmt.bindString(2, smobno);
   this.insertStmt.bindString(3, spicktime);
   this.insertStmt.bindString(4, sunit);
   this.insertStmt.bindString(5, sstreet);
   this.insertStmt.bindString(6, ssuburb);
   this.insertStmt.bindString(7, sstate);
   this.insertStmt.bindString(8, scity);
   this.insertStmt.bindString(9, sdestination);
   this.insertStmt.bindString(10, sfare);
   this.insertStmt.bindString(11, sgroup);

   return this.insertStmt.executeInsert();
   }

   public void deleteAll() {
   db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
   }

   public List<String[]> selectAll()
   {
   List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
   Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { "id","sename","smobno","spicktime","sunit","sstreet","ssuburb","sstate","scity","sdestination","sfare","sgroup" }, null, null, null, null, "sename asc");
   int x=0;
   if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
      do {
       String[] b1=new String[]{cursor.getString(0),cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),
         cursor.getString(3),cursor.getString(4),cursor.getString(5),
        cursor.getString(6),cursor.getString(7),cursor.getString(8),cursor.getString(9),cursor.getString(10),cursor.getString(11)};
       list.add(b1);
       x=x+1;
      } while (cursor.moveToNext());
   }
   if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
      cursor.close();
   }
   cursor.close();
   return list;
  }

    public ArrayList<member> getMembersList() {
ArrayList<member> user = new ArrayList<member>();

       String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM jobsend WHERE ssendjob LIKE '%One%'" ;

   Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);

    if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
       do {
       member contact = new member();
       contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
     contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));

     user.add(contact);
   } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
    }
         cursor.close();
return user;  

   }  


   public ArrayList<member> getMembersList2() {
ArrayList<member> user = new ArrayList<member>();

       String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM jobsend WHERE ssendjob LIKE '%Two%'" ;

   Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);

    if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
       do {
       member contact = new member();
       contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
     contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));

     user.add(contact);
   } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
    }
         cursor.close();
return user;  

   }  

  public void delete(int rowId) {
   db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
  }

  private static class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
   OpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
   }
   @Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, sename TEXT, smobno TEXT,spicktime TEXT, spickaddr TEXT , ssendjob TEXT, sunit TEXT, sstreet TEXT, sstate TEXT, sdestination TEXT, sfare TEXT, sgroup TEXT)");
   }

   @Override
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
       {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
   }
  }

public Cursor rawQuery(String selectQuery ,Object object) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

return null;
}    
public static SendJobDataBase getDBAdapterInstance(FragmentGroups viewPassword) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return null;
}
public Object getenternpw() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return null;
}
public static Cursor getSinlgeEntry() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

Cursor cur =db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+  TABLE_NAME, null);
// colName1+"='"+name+"'" ->  wherclause
System.out.println("Record count are "+cur.getCount());
return cur; 

}



static public void close() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
/* public SendJobDataBase open() throws SQLException {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
return this;
}   */
public SendJobDataBase getWritableDatabase() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return null;
}   


public void Delete_Contact(int id) {
SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
db.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_ID + " = ?",
new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
db.close();
   }


public ArrayList<member> Get_Contacts() {

try {
   user.clear();

   // Select All Query
   String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM jobsend";

   SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
   Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

   // looping through all rows and adding to list
   if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
do {
   member contact = new member();
   contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
   contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
 //  contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
//   contact.setEmail(cursor.getString(3));
   // Adding contact to list
   user.add(contact);
} while (cursor.moveToNext());
   }

   // return contact list
   cursor.close();
   db.close();
   return user;
} catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO: handle exception
   Log.e("all_contact", "" + e);
}

return user;
  }





public void insert(String sename, String smobile, String spicktime, String sstreet,
String sstate, String scity, String ssuburb, String sdestination,
String sgroup, String sfare, String msuburb, String login_token) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Comment: refer this http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a snippet code, that might be helpful for creating a SQLiteDB for android.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DataHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    /* DB Info*/
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION           = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME           = "TASP_JARVIS";
    public static DataHandler oDatabaseHander           = null; 

    /* Tables */
    private static final String     TABLE_WLANInfo      = "WLANInfo";

    /* WLAN Info Table*/
    private static final String     KEY_wlan_SerNo      = "SerNO";
    private static final String     KEY_wlan_IP         = "IP";
    private static final String     KEY_wlan_Port       = "Port";
    private static final String     KEY_wlan_Name       = "Name";
    private static final String     KEY_wlan_Type       = "Type";

    public DataHandler(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION); 
    }

    public static DataHandler getInstance(Context context) {

        // Use the application context, which will ensure that you
        // don't accidentally leak an Activity's context.
        // See this article for more information: http://bit.ly/6LRzfx

        if (oDatabaseHander == null){
            oDatabaseHander = new DataHandler(context.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return oDatabaseHander;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String CREATE_TABLE_WLANINFO       = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_WLANInfo + "("+KEY_wlan_SerNo+ " INTEGER ," +KEY_wlan_IP+ " TEXT ," +KEY_wlan_Port+ " INTEGER ," +KEY_wlan_Name+" INTEGER ," +KEY_wlan_Type+" INTEGER" + ");";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_WLANINFO);       

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_WLANInfo);

        /*Create tables again*/
        onCreate(db);

    }

    /* Insert WLAN Details */
    public boolean InsertWLANInfo(WLANInfo wlanInfo){

        long resvalue = -1; 
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
        values.put(KEY_wlan_SerNo, wlanInfo.getSerialNo());
        values.put(KEY_wlan_IP, wlanInfo.getIP()); 
        values.put(KEY_wlan_Port, wlanInfo.getPort());
        values.put(KEY_wlan_Name, wlanInfo.getName());
        values.put(KEY_wlan_Type, wlanInfo.getType());  

        resvalue = db.insert(TABLE_WLANInfo, null, values); 

        if(resvalue == -1)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    /* Fetch WLAN Information from table */
    public List<WLANInfo> FetchAllWLANDetails()
    {
          List<WLANInfo> WLANInfoList = new ArrayList<WLANInfo>();  
          String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_WLANInfo + "";  
          SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
          Cursor cursor = null;

          try{  
              cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

          if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
              if (cursor.moveToFirst())
                do{
                    WLANInfo  wlanInfo = new WLANInfo();

                    wlanInfo.setSerialNo(cursor.getInt(0));
                    wlanInfo.setIP(cursor.getString(1));
                    wlanInfo.setPort(cursor.getString(2));
                    wlanInfo.setIPName(cursor.getString(3));
                    wlanInfo.setType(cursor.getString(4));

                    WLANInfoList.add(wlanInfo);

                }while (cursor.moveToNext());

              cursor.close();
              return WLANInfoList;

          }else{
              cursor.close();
              return null;
          } 
        }
        finally{

            cursor.close();
        }
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot something to do. you're not even calling a function to open your database.

you can do it like:

```
db = new SendJobDataBase(getApplicationContext());   
db.open();

    db.insert(sename,smobno, spicktime, sunit, sstreet,sstate, ssuburb,scity, sdestination, sgroup, sfare);
```

but first uncomment this part on your SEndJobDataBase

```
/* public SendJobDataBase open() throws SQLException {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
return this;
}   */
```

hope it helps. Cheers!